# WPF TextBox autogrow

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a TextBox with a height=15 and width=50. I want the textbox to grow when the text size exceeds 50. I want to achieve this without using Width="Auto". Is there any way to achieve this? I tried TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap without any success.

Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 4):

Set the MinWidth=50

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your text box is inside a grid which has 2 columns

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   //The first column is used for a label
  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>

//This column is used for your text box
 <ColumnDefinition Width="*"
                   MinWidth="25"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Label Grid.Column="0"
         Content="Something:"
  />
  <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
          Content="BindToProperty"
    />
</Grid>
```

and the height and width of your user control is set to

> Auto

So whenever you place the user control on to other controls, it will have the minimum width of

> 25 + label width

. If you want to increase the width, you can set the width directly to your user control, and the Textbox will be stretched out.

Cheers